# Show that if n(A△B) is even then n(A) and n(B) are even

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question asked whether the statement is true or false and justify.

I am trying to use the identity
n(A)+n(B)−2n(A∩B)=n(A△B) but can't find to know where to start or go

Comment: Well, $2n(A \cap B)$ is obviously even, right?

Comment: Consider $A=B=\{42\}$ . . .

Comment: What are $A$, $B$ and $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write (assuming all the sets are finite)

$$A=\left(A\setminus B\right)\cup \left(A\cap B\right)\;,\;\;B=\left(B\setminus A\right)\cup \left(B\cap A\right)$$

and since each right side above is a disjoint union, we get

$$nA+nB=n(A\setminus B)+n(B\setminus A)+2n(A\cap B)$$

End now the argument using the definition of symmetric difference $\;A\Delta B\;$ ...

Comment: I was confused for the same reason. Shah wants the other implication. Of course, the symmetric difference can be empty when $A = B$, even when $|A|$ is odd... (as Henning Makholm points out)...

Comment: @AreaMan I can't see what the confusion is, unless I'm misunderstanding something basic or some notation. Also Henning's example fulfills the equation...

Comment: your true equation shows that A and B even implies the symmetric difference is even. But I see now that you didn't say anything about the other direction, so it seems like I was confused about what you intended to communicate. In any case, the question Shah is asking doesn't need this formula, since Shah was just looking for Hennings counter example. But all is well I think. +1 (even though you don't care about points.)

Comment: Yes I was looking at the converse of the other implication. So I have to start from the symmetric difference way

Comment: @DonAntonio: No, my example is a counterexample, because $\#(A\mathbin{\triangle} B)=0$ which is even, but $\#(A)$ and $\#(B)$ are _not_ even.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't see it that way...and perhaps it is my bad: in your example, $\;nA=nB=1,\,\,2n(A\cap B)=2\;$ , so left side of the OP's equaion is zero...just as the right side, $\;n(A\Delta B)=n\emptyset =0\;$ ...I can't see contradiction.

Comment: Oh, I see now my confusion! The **question's header** asks about the even thingy...I only considered the equation in the body of the question. Well, not the first time...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes, that's sloppy of the OP. Serves 'im right.